# Does hive table skip headers from all the files?

Tags: hive

Hive has an option `"skip.header.line.count"="1"` to make the external table to skip header from the file.

So, what would be the behavior if the folder has multiple files. Had this doubt and just verified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Header would be skipped on every file in the folder.**

If the folder (pointed by the table) had multiple files. Hive skips the first N rows ("skip.header.line.count"="N") from each and every file in the folder.